# how to run .exe (.bat) from JS in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, batch-file, exe

I've tried to change options in proxy-server, download old extensions (like activex hold), but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

You can not. It's a security feature. The only way to do it would be to create an application or script that will be installed alongside the extension, and which knows to listen to events such as with a socket or as a server, which the extension  would send a message to, and the server/application would use to run a script.